# minimal css/html text paragraphs next to image within list

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list (`ul`) with each `li` containing an `img` on the left and a text left aligned (title and one or more paragraphs) next to the image, on the right.

I played around with `float: left` and some `display` but can't get it working, the text float around (under) the image while I'd like to keep it left aligned but next to the image.

If possible I'd like to keep html and css to the minimal needed (and compatible with most browsers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img />
        <div>
             <span></span>
             <p></p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>



img, div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:right` for text (or the element which contains all the paragraphs of text) and then `clear:both` underneath or play a little bit with flexbox (preferable).

Answer (score 1):

Using the "before" pseudo selector could be a good way to go for the image.

Something like: https://jsbin.com/sumomebolu/edit?html,css,output

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li:before{
  content:url('url.jsg');
  position:relative;
  left:-20px;
}
```